# How to speed up SFTP transfers?

Tags: python, paramiko

I'm looking to push around 40-50 files totaling ~200 gb from one location to another, without downloading them to an intermediary location.  With filezilla, I can download a single file at ~17-28mbis.  With paramiko, the reading speed is a fraction of that.  (Uploading, by comparison, is super fast.)

I've tried chunking a bunch of different ways, changing the window size, and altering the max packets, which have all helped, but ultimately simply can't get faster than 300kbs.  Is there another way to approach this problem?

```
import paramiko
import math
import io
import time

transport = paramiko.Transport(host, port)
transport.connect(username = username, password = password)
sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport, window_size = 134217727, max_packet_size=pow(2,50))

chunk_size = 1024*250

for file in sftp.listdir():
    if 'SD_Demographic' in file:
        sftp_file = sftp.file(file, 'r')
        source_size = sftp_file._get_size()

        chunk_count = int(math.ceil(source_size / float(chunk_size)))

        for i in range(chunk_count):
            start = time.time()
            chunk = sftp_file.read(chunk_size)
            end = time.time()
            seconds = end - start
            print('%s read chunk from ftp (%i/%i) %ikbs' % (
                sftp_file, i + 1, chunk_count,
                math.ceil((chunk_size / 1024) / seconds)))
```

Comment: Just curious, did you try making `chunk_size` much larger than 250 kilobytes?

Comment: Yup.  Setting the chunk size at 25mb didn't see any improvement, unfortunately.

Comment: In FileZilla, are you referring to transfer speed of a single file? Or overall speed? FileZilla will transfer files in parallel, so it makes big difference. Make sure you compare comparable numbers. Give us numbers for a single file transfer only. Also it seems that the S3 part is not really relevant to this question, so consider simplifying the question to the download part only. And you can further simplify it to a single transfer only. Basically, we need [mcve]. Paramiko and FileZilla log file can help too.